# Css, Font-size, WP twenty Twelve theme Text letter (i) lowercase becomes uppercase with google fonts

Tags: php, css, text, transform

How does the php echo or print effects the letter lowercase to become uppercase? or is it a css issue?

for example:

```
echo "Against";
// Outputs AgaInst for me
```

in the css there is one parent class that says: text-transform:uppercase; but the specific title overwrites that css with text-transform:capitalize; if i just write it in plain html it works fine but when i echo it with php it does turn i to I!?

Please note the AgaInst and TIed in table headers. 
[image]

Found the solution as @Mathias Pointed out the font size.
Problem was the font size, it happens for for sizes smaller than font-size:12px;

Comment: Just Noticed if i turn off google fonts it works just fine but with google fonts it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like the fonts you are using has a missing glyph for small `i`

Comment: It is just the font, look at 'Tied'.

Comment: It could be a font rendering problem where the dot above the i is rendered to close to the i which makes it appear as a uppercase I. Try increasing the font-size to see the effect. Also what font is that?

Comment: @putvande doesn't happen for the country names though

Comment: Yeah, that indicates it's a problem with the weight. Increase the font size by a point or few pixels as mathias suggested.

Comment: And what is the name of the font?

Comment: as i explained there are two css classes one that says transform text to upper case and another that overwrites it with lowercase for table headers.
the country names does not have that css class. so its `css class` and `text-transform:uppercase and lowercase overwrites` that's when google fonts `can not render it correctly and gets confused with css classes ` i guess something like that.

Comment: @thomas Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700&#038;subset=latin,latin-ext

Comment: And what font-size do you have?

Comment: @Mathias Exactly the font size was 11px when i set it to 12px it does work fine. 
can you believe it its the original css class for WP twenty twelve theme.

Comment: I would suggest you edit the question and put in the info about the font, size and weight. And maybe also the bit about the WP theme :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the rendering of the font in that small size.

Try increasing the font size or use a different font. When I try Open Sans in 10px or smaller in Chrome on OSX I get the same effect. Different OS and different browsers might render the text differently.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has absolutely no effect what so ever, on the capitalisation of a string, unless passed through a string modification function.

The code `<?php echo 'Against';` will simply output the word `Against`. The display of this word is entirely up to the HTML, CSS, the viewing browser and even the viewing OS and machine.